Should a PDA reject words not in language?
Let's say we want to construct the PDA for the following language:
$$L_4 = \{w_1bw_2 | w_1, w_2 \in \{a,b,c \}^* \ and \ (\#ab\in w_1) = (2 \times \#c \in w_2)\}$$
Let's consider the following PDA that accepts the language:
$M = (Q = \{ s, q_1, q_2\}, \Sigma = \{ a, b, c\}, \Gamma = \Sigma \times\{ x\}, q_0 = s, \delta = \Delta, F = \{ q_2\})$, where $\Delta$ is:
$$
\Delta = \{( \\ 
(s, a, e),(q_1, e), \\
(q_1, b, e),(s, x), \ (1) \\
(s, b \ or \ c, e),(s, e), \\
(q_1, a, e),(q_1, e), \\
(q_1, c, e),(s, e), \\
(s, b, e),(q_2, e), \\
(q_1, b, e),(q_2, e), \\
(q_2, c, xxx),(q_2, e), \ (2) \\
(q_2, a \ or \ b, e),(q_2, e) \\
)\}
$$
In transition (1) the PDA pushes in stack an $x$ for every ab it detects and in transition (2) it pops three $x$'s for every c it detects.
PDA $M$ recognizes strings in $L_4$, but it can accept strings not in language, too.
Counterexample

$w_1 = ababbabab$
$w_2 = c$
$w = ababbababbc$ (4 ab instead of 2)

If $M$ makes the non-deterministic transition $s \rightarrow q_2$ in
w = ababbababbc
        ^

instead of
w = ababbababbc
             ^

it will accept the word with empty stack and final state.
Is this an expected behavior or the PDA should handle this case?

If your PDA, $M$, accepts words not in the language, $L$, then $M$ is not a PDA for the language $L$. However, I don't think your "counterexample" is an actual counterexample. By that, I mean $w=ababbababbc$ is an element of the language you have described, $L_4$. As you have noted, $w$ can be written as $w_1bw_2$ where $w_1=abab$ and $w_2=ababbc$, and the number of occurrences of the substring $ab$ in $w_1$ does equal the number of occurrences of $c$ in $w_2$. The fact that you can subdivide it into strings that don't fit the pattern is irrelevant. Any string in the language with at least one occurrence of $ab$ and another $b$ somewhere after can be divided into strings that don't fit the pattern by taking the "wrong" occurrence of $b$ to be the separator between $w_1$ and $w_2$.
